# How to intercept lazy loading related entities in EF

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

```
Product.Requests.Where(k=>k.IsActive==true)
```

I need to add this where condition in all my lazy loading related entities. Is there any generic way to add this? To intercept EF lazy loading?

Comment: And you wan to apply that condition **always** every time you want to load requests entities?

Comment: Yes, for each nested entity.